# Why is mktemp on OS X broken with a command that worked on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, shell

In Linux this shell script is suppose to work :

```
# Temporary directory for me to work in
myTEMP_DIR="$(mktemp -t -d zombie.XXXXXXXXX)"

# Change to temporary directory
cd "${myTEMP_DIR}"
```

However, when i perform this operation on my Mac, I get the following error:

```
dhcp-18-189-66-216:shell-scripting-sci-day2 myname$ myTEMP_DIR="$(mktemp -t -d zombie.XXXXXXXXX)"
dhcp-18-189-66-216:shell-scripting-sci-day2 myname$ cd "${myTEMP_DIR}"
-bash: cd: /var/folders/d8/b8d1j9x94l9fr3y21xrnc0640000gn/T/-d.QZDPA9Da
zombie.nwlEnHGDb: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know what is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: If you compared `man mktemp` on the two platforms, you'd see their differences in behavior documented. OS X and Linux occupy different parts of the Unix family tree, with the former being a BSD and the latter a mutt (with AT&T and GNU influences).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On Mac OS X, the `-t` option to `mktemp` takes an argument, which is a prefix for the temporary file/directory's name. On Linux, the `-t` argument just indicates that the prefix should either be the value of `$TMPDIR` or some default, usually `/tmp`.

So on Mac OS X, the invocation `mktemp -t -d zombie.XXXXXXXXX`, signifies `-t`with an argument is `-d`; consequently, `mktemp` creates a file whose name starts with `-d` inside `$TMPDIR` (`/var/folders/d8/b8d1j9x94l9fr3y21xrnc0640000gn/T/-d.QZDPA9Da`). Then, the template argument is used to create *another* file (`zombie.nwlEnHGDb`, in the current working directory). Finally, it prints *both* names to stdout, where they become the value of your variable `${myTEMP_DIR}` (complete with newline separator). Hence, the `cd` fails.

For a platform-independent call, avoid the `-t` flag and use an explicit template:

```
mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/zombie.XXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: @user40780: Remove -t *and* insert an explicit path to the created file.

Comment: Additional difference between macos and Linux: macos `mktemp` command only allows template "X"s as the suffix; whereas Linux allows the "X"s anywhere. Example, on macos: `mktmp /tmp/XXXXXX.tempfile` --> creates a file literally named `/tmp/XXXXXX.tempfile`; On Linux this would create a file `/tmp/B12nKS.tempfile` (i.e. the X's are replaced with random chars). Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and macos Sierra.

Comment: @JDS: Certainly true, but it doesn't stop my platform-independent call from being platform-independent, nor is it actually relevant to the question. There are other differences between the two utilities which also didn't seem relevant enough to confuse the situation.

Comment: @rici fair enough, especially re: the relevance to this question. I posted the comment because I couldn't find this particular difference whilst googling, and thought it would be good to mention it *somewhere*. Maybe not here though...

Comment: Just a little note that I moved the last `/` within the curly braces, ie: `mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/}zombie.XXXXXXXXX"` as it seems like $TMPDIR ends with a trailing slash, and I wanted to avoid a double `//` :)

Comment: @jack: but what if you run it on a system where `$TMPDIR` does not end with a slash? The fact that it ends with a slash on your system doesn't say anything about other peoples' systems. The double slash is harmless --it will be coalesced into a single directory separator-- but a missing slash will probably lead to failure.

Comment: Nice if they're always coalesced then that sounds like a better approach :)

Comment: @jack: [Posix Base Definitions, 3.271, Pathname](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271): "Multiple successive <slash> characters are considered to be the same as one <slash>, except for the case of exactly two leading <slash> characters."